# Using login form plugin with external database in Wordpress

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, authentication, elementor

How can I implement a login form in Wordpress using a plugin such as Jetblocks connecting to a `MySQL` external database and providing the hostname and port? Couldn't find any parameters or fields to customize this in plugin settings.

Answer (score 0):

You could try: https://wordpress.org/plugins/external-login/

rr write a plugin and override wp_authenticate.